# Stuck On Proof, I don't know how to continue or correct.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I know for this question, you can choose to make n = 2j or 2j+1, for some j of Integers. But I get $$j < \frac{1}{2}$$ and I know that I am doing this wrong because this value isn't an integer. How would you solve this proof?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What is $n$ if $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $1-n^2>0$?

Comment: Well, what do you mean exactly? I understand the first half of what you are saying but what does the 2nd portion mean exactly? Also, thank you.

Comment: Does this mean that n = 0?

Comment: Keep an eye on what tags you use.  All of your previous tag selections were entirely unrelated.  Proof-Explanation should only be used if you have a complete proof of someone else's that you have questions for clarification about.  Solution-verification is if you have a complete solution of your own that you want to check for correctness and ask for critiques on.  Linear-algebra and Calculus are about their own subjects respectively, this question not being a part of the subject material of those classes, and so on.

Comment: Yes, $n=0$, so $3n-2$ is even

Comment: OH! I get it now because if n was negative then it'd be false. Thank you!

Comment: @JMoravitz I am very sorry I just realized this. This was under my algebra calculus.

Comment: As for showing that $1-n^2>0$ implies that $n=0$., rearrange to see this is equivalent to $1>n^2$.  Then, recall that $n^2\geq |n|$ for all integers $n$.  For every nonzero integer $n$ you have $|n|\geq 1$ and so you have for every nonzero integer $n$ that $n^2\geq |n|\geq 1$ is not strictly less than $1$, thus $n$ is not non-zero.  It is easy to check however that $n=0$ does satisfy the condition, showing that $1-n^2>0$ is true if and only if $n=0$.

Comment: "But I get
$j<\frac 12$
and I know that I am doing this wrong because this value isn't an integer" But that's not an equal sign.  Its a less than sign.  And $0 < \frac 12$.  And $-1 < \frac 12$ and $-2 < \frac 12$.  etc.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $1-n^{2}>0$ means $n^{2}<1$, so $n$ must be $0$. Then, $3n-2 = -2$ is an even integer. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

The *only* value of $n$ that satisfies the left side of the implication is $0$. For this value, $3n-2=-2=2(-1)$. So the statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

> But I get
> $j<\frac 12$
> and I know that I am doing this wrong because this value isn't an integer

That's *less than* sign, not an equal sign.  There are *plenty* of integers that are *less* than $\frac 14$.

but that's not all you get.

So if $n = 2j$ and $n$ is odd then $1 -n^2 > 0$ so $1-4j^2 >0$ so $4j^2 < 1$ so $j^2 < \frac 14$.

If $j\ge 0$ then $0\ge j \le \frac 12$ but  if $j< 0$ then $-j \le \frac 12$ or in other words $-\frac 12 < j<0$.  So you have $-\frac 12 < j < \frac 12$.  Now there is only one integer between $-\frac 12$ and $\frac 12$.  So $j = 0$. and $n=2(0)=0$.

Now if $n = 2j+1$ we do the same thing but it's harder.  $1-(4j^2 +4j +1) > 1$ and so $-4j^2-4j >1$ so $4j^2+4j < -1$ so $j(j+1) < -\frac 14 < 0$.

So that means either $j+1 < 0$ and $j>0$.  Or $j+1 > 0$ and $j < 0$.

$j+1 < 0 < j$ is impossible.  And $j < 0 <j+1$ is impossible if $j$ is an integer.

So $n=2j+1$ is impossible.

but we didn't have to do that.

There's utterly no reason to treat $n$ even differently than $n$ being odd.

Just do $1-n^2 > 0$ so $n^2 < 1$.  So if $n\ge 0$ then $n< 1$ and $0\le n < 1$.  And if $n < 0$ then $-n < 1$ and $-1 < n$ and $-1 < n < 0$.  So either way, $-1 < n < 1$.  And there is only one such integer between $-1$ and $1$ not including $1$ or $-1$.  So $n = 0$.

And if $n =0$ then $3n -2 = 3(0) -2 = -2$ and that is an even number.